# Wrapping of C-code with a unique_ptr and custom deleter

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm trying to wrap an object from the C-API of OpenCV (CvPOSITObject) in a smart-pointer. To my understanding it should be something like the following:

```
unique_ptr<CvPOSITObject, decltype(cvReleasePOSITObject)> positObject;
positObject = unique_ptr<CvPOSITObject, decltype(cvReleasePOSITObject)>(cvCreatePOSITObject(param1, param2), cvReleasePOSITObject);
```

But I get a compiler error, and google didn't really help.

The declarations of the two functions are:

```
CVAPI(CvPOSITObject*)  cvCreatePOSITObject( CvPoint3D32f* points, int point_count );
CVAPI(void)  cvReleasePOSITObject( CvPOSITObject**  posit_object );
```

I get something like

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\memory(1227): error C2207: 'std::_Unique_ptr_base<_Ty,_Dx,_Empty_deleter>::_Mydel' : a member of a class template cannot acquire a function type
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\memory(1322): warning C4180: qualifier applied to function type has no meaning; ignored
1>  Myfile.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\memory(1221): warning C4180: qualifier applied to function type has no meaning; ignored
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\memory(1283) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Unique_ptr_base<_Ty,_Dx,_Empty_deleter>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=CvPOSITObject,
1>              _Dx=void (CvPOSITObject **),
1>              _Empty_deleter=false
1>          ]
1>          C:\MyDir\Myfile.hpp(71) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=CvPOSITObject,
1>              _Dx=void (CvPOSITObject **)
1>          ]
```

How do I do that correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. The first, as BenVoigt mentions in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19166376/241631), is that `decltype` will not trigger the implicit conversion from function type to pointer to function type, so you must take the address of the function explicitly. Your code changes to

```
positObject = unique_ptr<CvPOSITObject, 
                         decltype(&cvReleasePOSITObject)>(
                         cvCreatePOSITObject(param1, param2), 
                         cvReleasePOSITObject);
```

However, this will now fail to compile for a different reason, which brings us to the second problem. `cvReleasePOSITObject` takes an argument of type `CvPOSITObject **` but the `unique_ptr` above will attempt to call its deleter with `CvPOSITObject *`. To fix this, just use a lambda expression for the deleter.

```
positObject = unique_ptr<CvPOSITObject, 
                         void(*)(CvPOSITObject *)>(
                         cvCreatePOSITObject(param1, param2), 
                         [](CvPOSITObject *p) { cvReleasePOSITObject(&p); });
```

---

If you want to separate the declaration and initialization of the `unique_ptr` there are a couple of options. The first example demonstrates how to use a lamda expression for this.

```
auto deleter = [](int *p) {
    delete p;
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(deleter)> p(nullptr, deleter);    
    p.reset(new int(42));
}
```

You'll still have to pass the deleter instance to the `unique_ptr`, otherwise it'll attempt to default construct the deleter, which fails because closures generated from lambda expressions have deleted default constructors (*§5.1.2/20* from N3691).

The other option is to write the deleter as a functor, which allows default construction.

```
struct deleter
{
    void operator()(int *p) const
    {
        delete p;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int, deleter> p;

    p.reset(new int(42));
}
```

Comment: Compiles and looks like it does exactly what it should do. Thanks! Especially for the second part, which was very helpful!

Comment: Is there any way to split the variable declaration and the actual initialization? If I put all on one line, it works, if I split it I get an error "unique_ptr constructed with null deleter pointer".

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
decltype(&cvReleasePOSITObject)
```

There's an implicit conversion from the name of a function to a pointer to that function, but function types and function pointer types are not the same, and `decltype` doesn't cause implicit conversions.