# How do you create a custom deleter for a unique_ptr class member that wraps a c function which requires 2 arguments?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, unique-ptr, mupdf

I am trying to use mupdf to create a program (in Qt) that will allow me to list the objects of the document as a list and allow me to select which objects to render / not render.  Since Qt is c++, and I am more comfortable with it, I am trying to wrap structures defined in mupdf in C++ classes.

Right now my problem is this - one of the first things you do in mupdf is create a global context, that is passed around to everything, including functions that clean up and delete structures.

I am familiar with creating an object that has an overloaded `operator()`, much like:

```
struct ContextDeleter
{
    inline void operator()(fz_context* ctx)
    {
        fz_drop_context(ctx);
    }
};
```

which I can then hand to `unique_ptr` -

```
std::unique_ptr<fz_context, ContextDeleter> ctxPtr;
```

What I can't figure out is how to do the same thing with a function like:

```
fz_drop_page(ctx, page);
```

ie:

```
struct PageDeleter
{
     inline void operator()(fz_context* ctx, fz_page* pg)
     {
          fz_drop_page(ctx, pg);
     }
}
```

This is obviously incorrect, but is what I am trying to achieve.

How can I create a deleter for `unique_ptr` that includes 2 arguments (in this case the necessary context pointer)?  Is there a way for me to make `unique_ptr` aware of the context pointer to delete the page (in this example)?  Or (one thought I had) do I need to create something that wraps the `unique_ptr` so I can hand it the context for deletion later somehow (haven't fully thought it through yet).

I have seen the examples here:

[How do I use a custom deleter with a std::unique_ptr member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053351/how-do-i-use-a-custom-deleter-with-a-stdunique-ptr-member)

and

[Wrapping of C-code with a unique_ptr and custom deleter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166283/wrapping-of-c-code-with-a-unique-ptr-and-custom-deleter)

but I can't figure out how to make them work in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store the `fz_context *` in the deleter, and pass an instance of that deleter to the `unique_ptr` that holds the `fz_page *`

```
struct PageDeleter
{
    explicit PageDeleter(fz_context *ctx)
    : ctx(ctx)
    {}
    void operator()(fz_page* page) const
    {
        fz_drop_page(ctx, page);
    }
    fz_context *ctx;
};
```

Construct the `unique_ptr` as

```
fz_context *ctx = // get the fz_context
fz_page *page = // get the fz_page

PageDeleter page_del(ctx);
std::unique_ptr<fz_page, PageDeleter> pagePtr(page, page_del);
```

You could wrap all of this in a `make_unique_fz_page` function for convenience.

Comment: Unfortunetally, C++ has no concept of destructor arguments: if it did, you could reduce the state of your unique ptrs a touch.  It would be a strange, difficult language feature to add methinks.

Comment: The OP is looking for a `PageDeleter` implementation, but your example implemented `ContextDeleter` instead, which the OP already has a working implementation for. I updated your answer to swap the values around.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `std::unique_ptr` constructor with deleter directly is a bit of an annoyance with lambdas, because you cannot name the type. But you can infer the type using templates like this:

```
template <typename T, typename D, typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<T,D> make_unique_with_deleter( D deleter, Args&&...args )
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T,D>(
        new T( std::forward<Args>(args)... ), 
        std::move( deleter ) );
}
```

This way, you create a unique_ptr with lambda deleter directly in one place. Here's an example:

```
int main()
{
    const auto ctx = make_unique_with_deleter<fz_context>(
        []( fz_context * ctx ){ fz_drop_context( ctx ); }, 
        nullptr, nullptr, FZ_STORE_UNLIMITED );
    const auto page = make_unique_with_deleter<fz_page>( 
        [ctx]( fz_page * pg ){ fz_drop_page( ctx.get(), pg ); }, 
        ctx.get(), 1000000 );
    // and so forth ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a lambda that captures the `fz_context*` value, instead of storing it in a custom deleter:

```
fz_context *ctx = ...;
fz_page *page = ...;

std::unique_ptr<fz_page, std::function<void(fz_page*)>> pagePtr(page, [ctx](fz_page *page){ fz_drop_page(ctx, page); });
```

Or:

```
fz_context *ctx = ...;
fz_page *page = ...;

auto deleter = [ctx](fz_page *page){ fz_drop_page(ctx, page); };
std::unique_ptr<fz_page, decltype(deleter)> pagePtr(page, deleter);
```